# How do I add space between two active buttons

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-email

I am in the process of learning HTML to set up email campaigns at work. I have pulled some elements from a responsive template online. I have the following block of code, displaying two buttons. They display side by side, with no margin in between. I have tried many different things with no luck.

```
<td data-bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data-max="16" class="btn" align="center" style="font:12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#292c34; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding-alt:12px 10px 10px; border-radius:8px;" bgcolor="#8B0000">
                                                <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; padding:12px 20px 10px;" href="http://www.holidayvacations.net/index.php?page=catalog">Request a Catalog!</a>
                                            </td>


<td data-bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data-max="16" class="btn" align="center" style="font:12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#292c34; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding-alt:12px 10px 10px; border-radius:8px;" bgcolor="#8B0000">
                                                <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; padding:12px 20px 10px;" href="http://www.holidayvacations.net/hvadmin/uploads/Flip_Books/Catalog/Catalog.html">View Online Catalog!</a>
                                            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make box-sizing:border-box; property in a buttons container, and then try to margin them

Comment: I had done that using (<div class="container" padding="50px">) with no luck.

Comment: Is it because I am using "padding" verses border-box? I will try that now.

Comment: look, your markup could be
<div class="container">
<button class="btn1">...</button>
<button class="btn2">...</button>

</div>

Comment: css:
.container {box-sizing:border-box;
width:; 
}

Comment: sorry    , css: .container {box-sizing:border-box; width:; height:; } .btn1 {margin-right:; }  or padding-right

Comment: at the worst, use position: relative; posinioning

Answer (score 0):

Just move the definitions of `border-radius` and `bgcolor` to the buttons itself, than you can add `padding` on the `td` and it will do the trick. use `padding`:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data-max="16" class="btn" align="center" style="font:12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#292c34; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding-alt:12px 10px 10px; padding-right:5px; ">
      <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; padding:12px 20px 10px;background-color:#8B0000;border-radius:8px;" href="http://www.holidayvacations.net/index.php?page=catalog">Request a Catalog!</a>
    </td>


    <td data-bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data-max="16" class="btn" align="center" style="font:12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#292c34; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding-alt:12px 10px 10px;padding-left: 5px;">
      <a target="_blank" style="background-color:#8B0000;text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; padding:12px 20px 10px;border-radius:8px;" href="http://www.holidayvacations.net/hvadmin/uploads/Flip_Books/Catalog/Catalog.html">View Online Catalog!</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In email design there's no shame in using the non-breaking space character

`&nbsp;`

to force a space where you need it. All email clients tend to respect this and it's far more reliable than specifying padding and margin which some clients ignore or override.

As an aside, I don't know if you are testing in range of email clients, but if you need to make it work with Outlook and similar then css like border-radius won't be respected. This is a fairly good guide to what is safe: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/